# Commands from xparse inside functions created by \cs_new:Npn?

Tags: package-writing, latex3, expl3, xparse

Is it okay to put commands from `xparse` inside functions created by `\cs_new:Npn` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand`? Would that be a confusion of programming levels?

The example below works but I was wondering if it conforms to LaTeX3 conventions.

It tests `#1` for `-NoValue-`; but `#1` is an optional argument to public `\create` not to private `\__mypkg_create`.

### mypkg.sty:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mypkg}{2013/01/20}{0.01}{My Package}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \foo {om}
 {
    \__mypkg_foo:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__mypkg_foo:nn #1#2
 {
    \IfNoValueTF {#1} {true} {false}
 }
\endinput
```

### sample.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mypkg}
\begin{document}
\foo{bar}
\end{document}
```

## Edit:

### mypkg.sty:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mypkg}{2013/01/20}{0.01}{My Package}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \foo {om}
 {
    \mypkg_foo:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\cs_new:Npn \mypkg_foo:nn #1#2
 {
    \IfNoValueTF {#1} {true} {false}
 }
\endinput
```

Comment: Yes and no; the example seems quite contorted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it stands, you are making the error of using an internal command from a document command: that's not the approach the team is aiming for. One problem with LaTeX2e is that many document commands directly use internals, and that makes it very difficult to alter interfaces, internal commands, *etc.* safely. The LaTeX3 approach is therefore that each document command should be a simple 'translation' layer, taking a user syntax and turning into the input for a documented code-level interface

```
\NewDocumentCommand \foo {om}
  { \mypkg_foo:nn {#1} {#2} }
```

If you need to test for `\NoValue`, this would currently normally be done as part of this interface conversion

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \foo } {om}
  {
    \IfNoValueTF {#1} 
      { \mypkg_foo:nn { } {#2} }
      { \mypkg_foo:nn {#1} {#2} }
  }
```

(The exact detail of dealing with this 'special' token is still something that perhaps needs work.)

An alternative formulation would be

```
\NewDocumentCommand { \foo } { O { } m }
  { \mypkg_foo:nn {#1} {#2} }
```

where as we don't care if `#1` is present or not we simply set an empty default.

The reason for taking this approach is that it's then possible to redefine `\foo` while retaining access to the functionality of `\mypkg_foo:nn` (as it's documented). If you use an internal function inside `\foo` then you effectively tie the two together. (Note that getting this right is tricky, and parts of for example my own code need revision to get this correct. It's very much a work in progress.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand. There are at least 2 mistakes: (i) calling `\__mypkg_foo:nn` directly from within `\foo`; and (ii) calling `\IfNoValueTF` from within either `\mypkg_foo:nn` or `\__mypkg_foo:nn`.

Comment: @EduardoLima The first one is a definite mistake, the second is not quite the same as we've not tied down quite how that should work :-)

Comment: I think to have already said this, but I'll repeat anyway: an "internal" test for "NoValue" would be welcome. In your code you basically defer it to `\tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}`, but this is not general as one would like it to be.

Comment: @egreg I can see the argument for that, and indeed on of the reasons for having an expandable `\IfNoValue` is to allow use in `c`- and `x`-type contexts. I guess this needs raising (again) on LaTeX-L: I'll prod the team first and see what people think.

Comment: Joseph, I think you are not quite right here to call the same internal function when the document command has and doesn't have the optional argument.  I would find `\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{om}{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\mypkg_foo:n {#2}}{\mypkg_foo:nn {#1}{#2}}}` better.  This circumvents what @egreg says about the need of an internal test for `-NoValue-`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch In many cases this would lead to code duplication between the two functions.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch It depends on the use case and definition of `\mypkg_foo:nn`. Probably you would use simple `O{}` in the arg. spec. here, which again is a conceptual situation we've not really explored (is this 'sensible' or should you always know if there was no optional argument).

Comment: @egreg: well, either the code duplication is exact, in which case one function is a specialization of the other with a specific argument, or the code duplication is only partial, in which case one can call instead `\mypkg_foo:nnN {#1} {#2} \c_true_bool` and `\mypkg_foo:nnN { } {#2} \c_false_bool`, for instance.  Joseph, I think the whole point of `O` is for situations like you describe.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Updated example added