# If used insdide \cs_new(_protected), \IfNoValue(TF) doesn't detect -NoValue- at document-level

Tags: conditionals, latex3, optional-arguments, xparse

I guess my problem is related to [Commands from xparse inside functions created by \cs_new:Npn?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94821/commands-from-xparse-inside-functions-created-by-cs-newnpn) but I still don't understand what's going on: in the following WE (not minimal, sorry for this), why `\IfNoValueF` doesn't detect a `-NoValue-`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{datatool}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DTLnewdb{instrumentsdb}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mypkg_add_instrument:nnn
{%
  \DTLnewrow{instrumentsdb}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{instrumentsdb}{status}{#1}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{instrumentsdb}{name}{#2}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{instrumentsdb}{family}{#3}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \brass {om}
{
  \mypkg_add_instrument:nnn {#1}{#2}{brass}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \strings {om}
{
  \mypkg_add_instrument:nnn {#1}{#2}{strings}
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mypkg_display_instrument:nn
{%
  #2%
  \IfNoValueF {#1} {\\(#1)~(should~appear~only~if~"NoValue"~is~false) }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \displayinstruments {}
{%
  \begin{description}
  \item[Brass]\
    \begin{itemize}
      \DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\tl_mypkg_family}{brass}]{instrumentsdb}{%
        \tl_mypkg_status=status%
        ,\tl_mypkg_name=name%
        ,\tl_mypkg_family=family%
      }{%
      \item\mypkg_display_instrument:nn {\tl_mypkg_status}{\tl_mypkg_name}%
      }
    \end{itemize}
  %
  \item[Strings]\
    \begin{itemize}
      \DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\tl_mypkg_family}{strings}]{instrumentsdb}{%
        \tl_mypkg_status=status%
        ,\tl_mypkg_name=name%
        ,\tl_mypkg_family=family%
      }{%
      \item\mypkg_display_instrument:nn {\tl_mypkg_status}{\tl_mypkg_name}%
      }
    \end{itemize}
  \end{description}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\begin{document}
\brass[new]{trumpet}
\brass[used]{trombone}
%
\strings[used]{guitar}
\strings{violin}
%
\displayinstruments
\end{document}
```

[image]

In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94827/18401:

- it is advised to test for `\NoValue` in the interface conversion,
  that is within the definition of the document-level command. But, as
  hopefully pointed out in my example, it  would lead to code
  duplication: one could imagine more than `\brass`  and
  `\strings` document-level commands that need to test for
  `\NoValue`.
- an alternative is proposed:

  ```
  \NewDocumentCommand { \foo } { O { } m }
    { \mypkg_foo:nn {#1} {#2} }
  ```

  where as we don't care if `#1` is present or not we simply set an empty 
  default. But its "emptyness" cannot be tested neither, as pointed out by 
  the following similar WE.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,paperheight=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{datatool}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DTLnewdb{instrumentsdb}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mypkg_add_instrument:nnn
{%
  \DTLnewrow{instrumentsdb}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{instrumentsdb}{status}{#1}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{instrumentsdb}{name}{#2}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{instrumentsdb}{family}{#3}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \brass {O{}m}
{
  \mypkg_add_instrument:nnn {#1}{#2}{brass}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \strings {O{}m}
{
  \mypkg_add_instrument:nnn {#1}{#2}{strings}
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mypkg_display_instrument:nn
{%
  #2%
  \IfNoValueF {#1} {\\(#1)~(should~appear~only~if~"NoValue"~is~false) }%
  \tl_if_empty:nF {#1} { \\(#1)~(should~appear~only~if~false~"empty") }%
  \tl_if_blank:nF {#1} { \\(#1)~(should~appear~only~if~false~"blank") }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand \displayinstruments {}
{%
  \begin{description}
  \item[Brass]\
    \begin{itemize}
      \DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\tl_mypkg_family}{brass}]{instrumentsdb}{%
        \tl_mypkg_status=status%
        ,\tl_mypkg_name=name%
        ,\tl_mypkg_family=family%
      }{%
      \item\mypkg_display_instrument:nn {\tl_mypkg_status}{\tl_mypkg_name}%
      }
    \end{itemize}
  %
  \item[Strings]\
    \begin{itemize}
      \DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\tl_mypkg_family}{strings}]{instrumentsdb}{%
        \tl_mypkg_status=status%
        ,\tl_mypkg_name=name%
        ,\tl_mypkg_family=family%
      }{%
      \item\mypkg_display_instrument:nn {\tl_mypkg_status}{\tl_mypkg_name}%
      }
    \end{itemize}
  \end{description}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\begin{document}
\brass[new]{trumpet}
% \brass[used]{trombone}
%
\strings[used]{guitar}
\strings{violin}
%
\displayinstruments
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it was asked to the team to add a function like `\IfEmptyTF` or `\IfBlankTF` to `xparse`.

Comment: @Manuel 'blank' and 'empty' are not really interface things in the way an optional argument being missing is: that's why we have `\IfNoValue(TF)` but leave other tests to the code level.

Comment: @JosephWright I do miss “blank” anyways :) In any case, what I think is wrong here is using `\IfValueTF` outside `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: @Manuel One of the reasons `\IfNoVlaue(TF)` is expandable is that some people felt it should be usable 'lower down'. However, I'd concur with you: I feel it's a strictly interface thing and shouldn't propagate.

Comment: @JosephWright Because `\IfNoValue(TF)` is a pure `xparse` test, designed only
for testing if optional arguments of `xparse` commands are present or not, I understand now and agree
with you: it shouldn't propagate outside `xparse` commands. Anyway, AFAICS, it
is not the first time `LaTeX3` users (at least beginners like me) are bitten by
the lack of possibility to run such tests at the code level...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand  what is wrong with your code, I'd add a `\tl_show:n`

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mypkg_display_instrument:nn
  {
    \tl_show:n {#1}
    #2
    \IfNoValueF {#1} {\\(#1)~(should~appear~only~if~"NoValue"~is~false) }
  }
```

That will reveal that you are *not* getting `-NoValue-` as `#1`: you are getting `\tl_mypkg_status`. That's exactly what you'd expect from

```
\mypkg_display_instrument:nn { \tl_mypkg_status } { \tl_mypkg_name }
```

Probably you are looking to pass the *values* these variables hold

```
\mypkg_display_instrument:VV \tl_mypkg_status \tl_mypkg_name
```

with

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mypkg_display_instrument:nn { VV }
```

Note however that I'd be very wary of storing `-NoValue-` in the way you have: it's intended as a document interface marker which should be converted internally into a more appropriate form. For example, as you are storing the fact that something is missing, I'd be much more inclined not to store it at all and pick this up on recovery.

Comment: Passing the values these variables hold work like a charm! But I don't see your point when you say you'd "be much more inclined not to store it at all and pick this up on recovery": do you mean duplicate the `\IfNoValueF {#1} {...}` in each document-level command?